# Interesting difference between רבנים and דיינים

Tags: torah-study, sukkah

> רבנן דקיסרי ואמרי לה דייני דקיסרי אמרי ...
>
> The Sages of Caesarea, and some say that it was the judges of Caesarea, said that ... ([Succah 8b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.8b?lang=bi))

I'd assume that רבנים are דיינים and vice verse. But here, seemingly, there's a distinction.

What is the practical difference (נפקא מינא) here between רבנן and דיינים for the Sugiya?

Comment: I think it was just two different groups of rabbis who lived in Casesaria, and the people who brought down their opinion didn't remember which group it was.    See also Sanhedrin 17b "בי אמי ורבי אסי דייני דפומבדיתא רב פפא בר שמואל דייני דנהרדעא רב אדא בר מניומי סבי דסורא רב הונא ורב חסדא סבי דפומבדיתא רב יהודה ורב עינא חריפי דפומבדיתא עיפה ואבימי בני רחבה אמוראי דפומבדיתא"

Comment: @Nic Very probable, but what's נ"מ? Your example seems more clear, but רבנים and דיינים don't look like two groups IMHO

Comment: Why does there need to be a specific distinction?   Why can't it simply be important to record which rabbis had which opinions?